# Protect against pseudonymous identity activity on a forum and traffic correlation?

Tags: anonymity, deanonymization, attacks, information-leaks

I use Tor when I need to use a pseudonymous account on a forum. A observer can see when I connect to Tor and correlate with activity of the account from the forum 
How I can protect against this ?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the observer is watching all the traffic from your computer and also that specific server, I think your best bet to help mask your activity is to make sure you use Tor for more than just visiting that server. Even then, if they are watching both your traffic and the server's, I don't think there is a way to totally prevent correlation discovery.